# AJAX, JQuery, calculate price after button click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I want to calculate the price after a button click.
I have 3 buttons which are selectable.
For example : button1 = 50$, button2 = 100$, button3 = 200$
Now I want to update the price after a button click.
Is there any solution to handle this? Because, If i send the Ajax request and update my html-element the price isn't added. My old price always disappear. 
So if the user selects button1 the price is 50$, but if the user also selects button2 my price is 100$, not $150.

Thanks :)

Comment: You should give us code, because without it we can just tell you to make a sum. :)

Comment: There are tons of solutions but the question is `what have you tried?` show us your `code`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the idea:

```
<script>
    function add(x) {
        document.getElementById('result').innerText =  +(document.getElementById('result').innerText) + x;
    }
</script>
<form>
    <input type="button" onclick="add(50)" value="50">
    <input type="button" onclick="add(100)" value="100">
    <input type="button" onclick="add(200)" value="200">
</form>
<div id='result'></div>
```

Note: +(x) forces conversion of x to number